# Does flow's structural subtyping "forget" specific subtype properties?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype, static-typing, structural-typing

I am currently studying structural typing. I am skeptical about the idea that two types are considered equivalent just because they happen to have a portion of their structure in common. This feels a lot like static duck typing and it completely ignores the semantic level of types. So I took a closer look at flow's structural typing of ordinary objects and have encountered the following behavior:

```
const o:{} = {foo: true};
o.foo; // type error
```

`{}` is a structural type and the supertype of all ordinary objects. Hence it makes sense that I can annotate `o` with it, because `{foo: true}` is a structural subtype of `{}`. However, when I try to access the existing `foo` property, this operation doesn't type check. This is odd because AFAIK a structural subtype can usually contain specific properties as long as it also includes all required properties of its supertype.

It seems as flow's structural subtyping algorithm occasionally forgets properties that are specific to a certain subtype. Is this behavior intended or did I just run into an edge case?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? By declaring the type `: {}`, you've explicitly erased the type information about it, just like if you did `Animal foo = new Cat()`, `foo` doesn't know it's a `Cat`, it just knows it is an `Animal`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth `{}` is just the most general ordinary object type without any structure. It is pretty useless of course. The question is if the behavior I have observed with this edge case is part of a deeper problem, which is specific to subtyping.

Comment: What I'm trying to clarify is, what about this do you view an an edge case, and what about it would be a problem? In the case of JavaScript as a untyped language, there are absolutely cases where you'll have an object and not know anything about the properties it has. To get at `foo` you can do `if(typeof o.foo === "boolean") { /* do stuff with the property as a boolean */ }` and it'll work great.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to clarify that `{}` is "an object with unknown properties" which can be useful, whereas `{||}` is "an object with no properties" which is pretty useless.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I do not know how to express my q any better, sorry. Actually, it doesn't matter if we consider `{}` as an object without or with unknown props. Here is another example: `type O = {foo: boolean}; const o:O = {foo: true, bar: 123};`. This works because the type of `o` is a structural subtype of `O`. Now when I try to access `o.bar`, a property which is specific to the subtype, I get a type error. This doesn't seem correct.

Comment: `o` is an object that has the property `foo` and `bar`, but because you've cast it to a supertype `O`, the type system doesn't know that it has the property `bar` anymore. It's the same type of failure you see in something like https://ideone.com/i9SjfW. Once you've told the type system that it is an `O`, that's all it knows. Yes the object has other properties, but you've explicitly told the type system to forget they are there. Flow's structural types are what allows you to cast them, but you get the same issue with a class hierarchy too if you cast to a supertype.

Comment: If you extend the toy examples given to any real-world code, it quickly becomes impractical to ask the type checker to analyze all possible sources of a value and ignore the type annotations you have actually given in favor of the additional information it has inferred.

Answer (score 2):

The overall issue you're describing is a fact of casting from a subtype to a supertype. By performing the cast, you're explicitly telling the compiler to discard information about a given object.

For instance, even without structural typing, if you do

```
class Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {
  foo: bool = true;
}

const c: Animal = new Cat();

console.log(c.foo);
```

([On flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDG0CGBnToCCA7ASwFt1pQBvAX2TSxwGF0AXUAUwA9m38ATHAiTKVEoUJFiwAXKABGk8gF5QzAE4BXNgG5ENVLHyZWKGYNJLQ+NvFBNmACgCUO-YdjQ2AOjgBzeyk8JWGcgA))

it fails to typecheck for the same reason. In your example you've explicitly told the compiler "consider `o` to have the type `{}`", just like in my example I've said "consider `c` to have the type `Animal`". Because of that, the compiler has explicitly been told to forget that it is working with a `Cat`, therefore it forgets that the object has a `.foo` property.

> It seems as flow's structural subtyping algorithm occasionally forgets properties that are specific to a certain subtype. Is this behavior intended or did I just run into an edge case?

So to answer this, it doesn't do it "occasionally", it does it exactly when you tell it to do it. The behavior is absolutely intended.

> This is odd because AFAIK a structural subtype can usually contain specific properties as long as it also includes all required properties of its supertype.

The *object* does contain that property, which is 100% fine, but you've explicitly erased that information by casting the value to a supertype.

Comment: This was with certainty not one of my best questions. Thanks for taking the time to answer it anyway! So the real question is how flow behaves when there isn't any explicit annotation but the type has to be inferred, because an object is returned by a function within a more complex composition. Is there an information loss too? Related: [subsumption rule](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13047934)

Comment: I feel like I'd need an explicit example, but as far as I know there shouldn't be any information lost in type inference.